# Toshiba Laptop Battery Charger

Tags: laptop, battery, toshiba-laptop, charger

I have a Toshiba laptop (Satellite M115S3114). The charger details are as below -

1. Model - SADP75PB A
2. Input - 100-240V ~ 1.5A 50-60Hz
3. Output - 15V---- 5A

This charger has now become faulty. And, when I look up for a replacement in Amazon, I do not find a exact replacement.

I did check on Google / Amazon, but none of them are by the OEM. Is it OK to purchase something that is not by the OEM??

Comment: Google found several.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: I did Google, but then none of them are OEM. I just needed recommendation on whether we can buy the one that is not by the OEM. The question has been edited to reflect the same.

Comment: This isn't quite about shopping... it's more whether something works or not.

Answer (score 2):

We regularly buy non OEM adapters. Check that the electrical details are all the same and you'll be fine. They usually tend to be cheaper too.

One thing I regularly see people mention is to check the polarity. Just worth mentioning.